# Recovery my data on internal storage (deleted permanently 1 month ago)

Tags: rooting, root-access, data-recovery

Does software like Dr. Fone, MiniTool that required "root" on android really work 100% for recovering my lost photo?

First of all *my phone is not rooted.*

I've lost my important photo (deleted permanently) which I kept in internal storage. And recently i always keep my phone clean that is always using cleaner app like CCleaner for cleaning my DCIM folder, thumbnails, and cache. And i've tried a lot of app like DiskDigger and another app in playstore for recover my photo, but they didn't work.

And my last hope is rooting my phone and use software like Dr. Fone, or MiniTool. (If these gonna work)

And i'm really really searching the accurated answer here which will advise me for rooting my phone or not. Because as you know, rooting is very dangerous cz i have bad experience with rooting. I mean if there is no way to recovery my data so i oughtn't to root my phone.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for your loss but it's almost certainly impossible to recover deleted data if your phone is not already rooted. Rooting usually requires unlocking bootloader which is supposed to erase whole internal storage permanently. Also 1 month is a long period, data must have been overwritten several times by now. See [How to make a complete factory reset, without anyone being able to retrieve my data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214496/218526). Apps claiming data recovery without root mostly make false or ambiguous claims.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thanks for the answer before. And actually that doesn't answer my question either. So actually i've heard about someone losing his data for 6 months, and somehow it still can be recovered. I don't know how, but certainly it requires root. I'm here for convincing myself to rooting is wise as a way for recovering my photo.

Comment: no, these tools don't work 100% for recovering your lost photos. Furthermore it is IMPOSSIBLE please READ linked questions

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219346