# Can't access my phone memory suddenly after using SD card as internal memory

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

A few weeks ago I integrated my SD card to use as phone memory. Everything was fine until a couple of days ago.

All of a sudden I saw the "insert SD card" notice appear on the notification bar. I open the back cover but the SD card looked like it was in place. I remove it and insert it back and the notice disappears. But then I notice that when I go to file explorer (FX) to access my files, it says "Access was denied". I can't access anything that is on my phone memory, although the apps are working. I guess system files are OK, but everything else is not.

My phone is rooted so I tried to access the files through TWRP but I can only see system folders.

Phone is a Moto C plus. Nougat.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decrypt the corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135803/how-to-decrypt-the-corrupt-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage)

Answer (score 2):

You can recover some files from corrupted MicroSD Card. [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) is encrypted, it requires the encryption key from the source device. In your case you are lucky your device is rooted

- insert MicroSD Card into PC Card Reader. figure out which one is the correct block device (`/dev/sdc`) with `sudo blkid`
- mount your hard drive (`/media/xubuntu/404CCE454CCE3606`). check free disk space with `df -h`
- clone 1:1 disk image of the entire MicroSD Card with `gddrescue`

  ```
  sudo -i
  apt install gddrescue
  cd /media/xubuntu/404CCE454CCE3606
  ddrescue -n -b512 -r3 /dev/sdc sd.img gddrescue_sd_img.log
  ```
- install android [platform-tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads)

  ```
  apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
  ```
- connect your device in recovery mode (TWRP)
- get the encryption key file `expand_5f5e697154132edfaa6fca7ac23cde2a.key` (root access required)

  ```
  adb devices
  adb pull /data/misc/vold
  ```
- read the 16-bytes hex encryption key (`ae126af293501cd130db0637372e8911`)

  ```
  ls vold
  hexdump -v vold/expand_5f5e697154132edfaa6fca7ac23cde2a.key
  ```
- map the image file to create loop devices

  ```
  kpartx -av /media/xubuntu/404CCE454CCE3606/sd.img
  ```
- get partition size (`62299103`) and decrypt the 2nd partition (`/dev/mapper/loop1p2`)

  ```
  blockdev --getsize /dev/mapper/loop1p2
  dmsetup create crypt1 --table "0 62299103 crypt aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 ae126af293501cd130db0637372e8911 0 /dev/mapper/loop1p2 0"
  ```
- when successfull a new (decrypted) block device `/dev/mapper/crypt1` (ext4) will created
- mount the partition (**skip** this step Xubuntu will auto mount)

  ```
  mkdir /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448
  mount -t ext4 -o ro,noexec,noload /dev/mapper/crypt1 /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448
  ```
- Open new terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and start File Manager (root session) from command line:

  ```
  sudo thunar /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448
  ```
- in File Manager enable - *View - Show Hidden Files*
  you should see some directories

  ```
  app
  local
  lost+found
  media
  misc
  user
  user_de
  ```
- you can now browse `media` directory for *Internal Storage* and copy your Pictures to your hard drive

Be aware you can't copy `app` directory to windows hard drive, because linux permissions and file names aren't compatible with NTFS file system type

- however, you can create tarball archive to preserve the whole partition content including all metadata

  ```
   sudo -i
   cd /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448
   tar --selinux --xattrs -H posix --numeric-owner -vcp * | gzip -cn > /media/xubuntu/404CCE454CCE3606/sdcard.tar.gz
  ```
- `sdcard.tar.gz` can be unpacked with [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org) in windows, or restored from twrp command line with [GNU tar](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2649724&goto=newpost)

Comment: on the last step, can you please double check disk usage of *sd.img*? are there files in it? (if you already have *sd.img* skip creating again and start with *kpartx*) when mounted run `df -h /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448` or `find -type f /media/xubuntu/fa6c4c4c-846e-4c6f-8c02-e93cf5ebf448`

Comment: I can see in the phone system root folder in the phone. And it has only 203 MB as well. My concern is...if I "forget" the SD card, will I lose the files from the "phone" internal storage? Because right now I can't access the phone internal storage. I can only see the system folder. But I can see the folders in the adopted SD card (which are almost empty).

Comment: but what about the files in sd.img?

Comment: Size: 30G | Used: 239M | Avail: 29G

Comment: Could it be that it was saving most of the data (or all of it) in the internal phone memory instead of the SD card even though they are both integrated? But now my files are being held hostage in the phone memory. If I want to "unlink" or "unadopt", what are my choices? From what I can see, there are 3 ways...1) insert a new SD card and adopt it as internal storage WITHOUT "forgetting" the first SD. 2) "Forget" the adopted SD 3) "Migrate" the files from the internal storage option (even though it says "it will free 0 bytes on SD card"). And then "format" the SD card as portable". Which one?

Comment: if 1) is possible that seems the best option

Comment: you should run extundelete or testdisk or photorec or binwalk on /dev/mapper/crypt1 maybe there can be some files recovered (search for that keywords here or www)

Comment: "Sudo extundelete /dev/mapper/crypt1 --restore-all" ??

Comment: yes that will scan for deleted files based on inodes. you can also run these tools on your internal storage data.img

Comment: From TWRP?.....

Comment: to create such image (if don't have already) run that command while connected in TWRP:
*'adb pull /dev/block/dm-0 data.img'* or if not encrypted *'adb pull /dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/userdata data.img'*

Comment: with this tools you can scan your internal storage and your adoptable storage for deleted files as well. photorec is more powerful, binwalk the deepest file search. testdisk has also some options to restore deleted files but that tool is more for repairing partition tables and maybe just as good as extundelete

Comment: here is example usage for testdisk (little complicated) the red files on that screenshot are deleted ones https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219364 see you tomorrow, it's late

Comment: I'm running extundelete and it's taking a long time. There is no indication so I have no idea if it's working or it hang.

Comment: Where is it created?

Comment: check home directory ~/RECOVERED_FILES