# Can't install any apps that were previously saved on SD card

Tags: applications, sd-card, installation

Recently my SD card stopped working and all apps that were saved to the SD card were obviously gone however the problem is while the phone, LG G6, still works and I'm able to install apps through Google play store I can't install any of the apps that were previously saved on that SD card. I've tried all the troubleshooting options, except resetting my phone, I don't want to lose what's left on my phone. The SD card was removed as soon as it became a problem, with it in the phone wouldn't work at all. Any suggestions?

Comment: consider 1:1 clone with gddrescue that way you may get all your data back from broken MicroSD card https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222394

Comment: if you don't want to recover MicroSD card you must forgetting sdcard in settings. be aware that will delete encryption key and sdcard is not recoverable anymore. make sure you forget the right one or you will lose more data again