# Reading corrupted android internal memory sd card

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

Please I have a Huawei p8 lite phone and I mounted an sd card as internal storage since I don't money for phone with a bigger memory. After using it for months with most of my important documents inside, it's telling me that the sd card is corrupt and need to be formatted but I can't do that because of my stuffs inside. Please how can I access the card to save my data? I tried using huawei Hisuite, it installed on pc but can't install on my phone, telling me my device is outdated. Can I use p20 to do it, will this card from p8 be read in p20 or any possible way for me to save my data? Thanks so much.

Ps. I'v also installed an older version of Hisuite on my phone but it didn't work.

Comment: When formatted as internal the SD-card is encrypted and can only be read by the device that has encrypted it. Therefore all attempts to access it on a PC can not work by definition. You can only use the PC to make sure the whole SD-card can be read on raw level using a tool like Win32DiskImager.

Comment: buy another MicroSD Card and 1:1 clone with gddrescue. if you are lucky the new MicroSD Card is decryptable on unrooted device https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222394

Comment: @Robert wrote *"When formatted as internal the SD-card is encrypted..."*. To clarify, for which versions of Android is that valid? All of them or just more recent ones?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket As far as I know this applies to every Android version. ["When external storage media is adopted, it’s formatted and encrypted to only work with a single Android device at a time."](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable?hl=en) ("with a single device" means that it is bound to the device).

Comment: @Robert Thank you, Robert, for the quote and the link.