# SD card / card slot suddenly stopped working

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card

My sd card (or my sd card slot) suddenly stopped working.
All of the apps that used the SD card don't work anymore (obviously), however also other apps have problems. My banking app won't start. The google play store won't let me install any app (no warning, it just stops working). I have to fix that.

My questions are:

1. how to disable the 'sd storage' for the play store?

Right now I cannot install any app, because play store wants to use the sd card as storage. I spent an hour trying to find a way to disable the 'sd storage' in the play store, but I haven't found a
solution. I cannot 'normally' migrate the apps using the settings->storage menu back to the memory, because the sd card is shown as 'corrupted'

2. how to repair the sd card?

I have a ton of semi-important files on the sd card. I can't simply format it. Is there any software to mount and analyze the card?

I am using Android 9 on Umidigi A5 Pro

Comment: 1. where do you get the idea that play store wants to use the sd card as storage? 2. is your SD Card formatted as internal [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)?

Comment: 1. I am not sure. However when I click the 'install' button in the play store it becomes gray for few seconds, the notification 'sd card not ready' pops up, and I the 'install' button refreshes - becomes green again.  2. Yes, I have been using it for one year. I have a huge app, that was installed on the sd card, and needed to update it (ca 4gb of data). The update somehow 'broke' the card, and it is inaccesible.

Comment: on unlocked bootloader *'fastboot boot TWRP_Hadenix-A5Pro.img; adb shell twrp decrypt 1234; adb pull /data/misc/vold;*' to obtain encryption key

Comment: For analyzing an sd-card use an USB sd-card reader and connect it to a PC. There you can check what files are on the sd-card.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access my phone memory suddenly after using SD card as internal memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222394/cant-access-my-phone-memory-suddenly-after-using-sd-card-as-internal-memory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access my phone memory suddenly after using SD card as internal memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222394/cant-access-my-phone-memory-suddenly-after-using-sd-card-as-internal-memory)

Comment: I managed to disable the sd storage, and I am able now to use the internal memory for any operations.
I did it this way: I tried to install an app->android told me that there is no memory free->I entered the 'memory settings' -> I chose 'forget sd card'.

From this point on I am able to use internal storage to use the phone normally