# Unable to access my data on the same device on which I mistakenly selected SD card to be used as adoptable internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, data-recovery, data-corruption

Currently using pixel experience rom based on Android 12, by mistake selected sd card as adoptable internal storage and migrated my data   - Esp Images & videos- to adopted sd card. And then foolishly removed and reinserted my sd card multiple times without selecting 'Eject' or 'Unmount'. Now I am unable to access my photos & videos even on the device in which the sd card was encrypted and used as adopted storage let alone reading the sd card data on computer or any other device. In the same device I can only see the thumbnails of around only 20-30% of photos & videos and when selecting those photos/files individually the photo/file appears blurry & just keeps loading and the rest 70% files/photos, when opened, display the error 'could not open file'. I have not factory reset my device or erased any of internal storage which means the key to decrypt is still inside internal storage but my device is not rooted. Can someone please help me out so that I am able to access my data/ precious memories?? I'd really appreciate any help to solve this problem and get me out of this stressed out situation.

Comment: Honestly it sounds to me like you the SD card is corrupt or failing... I would connect your phone to a PC via USB and copy the data off the card as soon as possible. These issues have a tendency to escalate until the entire thing is inaccessible. The likelihood of being able to recover these photos/videos is slim since this is an encrypted volume. The alternative would be to put the card in a card reader in a Linux PC and use the process of recovery since you have an unlocked/rooted device already and can access the decryption key.

Comment: I have copied all data esp Media- photos& videos on my computer but the data was neither readable on the mobile device nor it is readable on the PC. And now I have formatted the MicroSD card to be used as a portable storage but the card is displaying an error of currupt SD card. So I again turned the formatted card as Transportable internal storage because no media was left in the device so nothing shifted into Transportable storage except some system files. My Nokia 6.1+ has an unlocked Bootloader but is not Rooted. Is there any way to make the backed up data on my PC readable by Rooting????

Comment: I copied some files/photos from the backed up data on PC to this Transportable internal Storage in the hope that may be it becomes readable but it is still not readable. I have only formatted the Sd card but have not formatted/ not factory reset my Phone internal storage which is hopefully still containing the key to decrypt the data. After Rooting the device, is there a way to make my data readable by using the key??? Do I still have a chance left to access my data?? I don't know how to read the key & use it to decrypt data.Can someone help me out with this situation??

Comment: Let me get this straight... You copied the data off, then formatted the card, then formatted it back to adopted storage? If that is correct, you are totally screwed if you didn't get the key off the phone before you formatted the card and readopted it, because a new key is generated every time storage is adopted, the original key would be overwritten and it is gone. That said, the device is telling you the card is bad, THROW IT AWAY AND GET A NEW ONE!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access my phone memory suddenly after using SD card as internal memory](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222394/cant-access-my-phone-memory-suddenly-after-using-sd-card-as-internal-memory)

Comment: I am a noob when it comes to technical matters so pardon me if questions are a bit silly.

Comment: If I patch the boot.img using Magisk, would I get access to the decryption key??? As u said that since I formatted the Sd card as portable and adoptable storage multiple times & then repeated the same again on another Sd card multiple times, the Original Key was overwritten on. Can the Final Key Decrypt the Data encrypted the 1 St time??? Can we somehow get the 1st original key using the Final Key ????

Comment: I am ready to give remote access.Can I get someone online who can do this process for me? Or atleast give me Instructions in layman terms so that I can 1st Root device and be able to read the Final Key. Then using that Final key keys how to decipher the original key for decryption!

Comment: If I manage to find the key / different keys . Then how to use the key to Read the backed up data stored on my PC? Can I make it readable somehow on the PC or have to do it in Android? If on Android, with the help of key  how to do it?

Comment: I don't have that corrupt sd card anymore. Have already returned it and got a new one. All I have is the Key/keys stored in my android system internal storage & the backed up data on my PC!

Comment: I now have Root access on the device. Can you tell me how to find this /data/misc/vold folder and read the Key/Keys & then make the backed up data on my PC readable??

Comment: use current SD Card and follow the linked [steps](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247583/unable-to-access-my-data-on-the-same-device-on-which-i-mistakenly-selected-sd-ca#comment332402_247583) for exercise to get a feeling how things work. all your questions will be answered during this homework (spoiler: it's pointless)