# How to Read the Key from phone internal storage generated when formatted sd card as internal storage?

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, encryption, internal-sd, reading

If I manage to get root access to my device, where to find and how to read the decryption Key?

I selected sd card to be used as internal storage and removed it without Using 'Eject' , that too multiple times, which corrupted the data. The data was not readable even in the same Android device in which the sd card was formatted as transportable internal storage. So transferred all important data- images and videos to my computer.

Then reformatted the sd card as portable storage then again Transportable internal storage multiple times & did the same thing with another sd card just to somehow make the data readable by transferring it from my computer into it but could not make it Readable.

All these transfers on the two different s
d card formatted as internal storage may have changed the Key inside the Android device system.

Can the Final Key be used to get the original 1st Key which was generated the very 1st time when sd card was formatted as internal storage?

If so,

- How to read the Final key ?
- How to get the original Key??
- How to use the key to decrypt the backed up data storage on my computer?

Comment: Possibly related/duplicate: [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145443/44325) (though might be outdated)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access my data on the same device on which I mistakenly selected SD card to be used as adoptable internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247583/unable-to-access-my-data-on-the-same-device-on-which-i-mistakenly-selected-sd-ca)