# How to access the block device that represents the SD card on an android device thru ADB?

Tags: adb, data-recovery

My android's SD card got corrupted while trying to access the data with a card reader. I'm trying to create a dd image of the block device that represents the SD card. Can this be achieved thru ADB (Android Debug Bridge)?  Don't want to reduce my chances of data recovery even further. This is for an android 11 device. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Accessing a block device on Linux requires root permissions (thus a rooted device).

Comment: Let's assume I have rooted the device already. What commands do I need to execute to create the SD card image in my computer? Thanks!

Comment: On that level Android is simply a Linux system so `dd` or if you can find a version for arm/arm64 `dd-rescue` can create an image of a block device.

Comment: not for android 11 but the cloning of MicroSD card is the same https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222394

Comment: Thank you for the guidance so far.