# How to recover lost/deleted images

Tags: applications, data-recovery, photos, file-transfer, data-transfer

So basically it went like this:

1.) I plugged my phone to my laptop and transferred all my photos.

2.) After having successfully copied the pictures, I deleted them on my phone via the laptop then unplugged it after.

3.) I checked my laptop and there was one album that was empty. I tried checking it on my phone but the album wasn't there.

What happened and is there any possible methods in recovering the album?

Comment: The used protocol via USB is MTP and this protocol is very fragile. Also in older Windows versions some bugs are known which can even destroy files on the phone. For reliable file copy it is better to enable debugging options and  Android Debug Bridge (`adb`)  and use it for file sync , e.g. via adb-sync.

Comment: possible methods in recovering the album depends on phone model (for mediatek chipset try [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219346)) also some people claim disk digger is working. in general the chance is very low to zero, there is no hope