# Retrieve DCIM folder deleted from internal storage, no backup on Google and phone is unrooted

Tags: data-recovery, hardware

I accidentally deleted files including photos from file manager. I tried multiple recovery apps like Dr. Fone, disk digger, etc. but nothing seems to work as my thumbnails, cache and everything from the recycle bin has been deleted. Google photos also doesn't have backup. Can anyone suggest how to retrieve data, especially the DCIM folder without rooting my phone?

Comment: not possible. but you can search for trash or thumbnail folders https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.i8dudata.imgrecover.free

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pull data from internal memory on an unrooted phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219346/how-to-pull-data-from-internal-memory-on-an-unrooted-phone)