# What is 0x10DB21 error code in Kingoroot?

Tags: rooting

I'm currently using android 6.0
And i wanted to root it
I downloaded kingoroot apk
I installed it clicked one click root and it stopped at 90% and then said failed to root error 
0x10db21 what do i do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are the rooting apps not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205706/why-are-the-rooting-apps-not-working-anymore)

Comment: there is currently one [app](https://github.com/JunioJsv/mtk-easy-su) still working with [exploit](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) (Mediatek Chipset only)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

## Kingoroot does not work for Android 6

The vulnerability it uses for gaining root as been fixed in Android 6 and newer. Hence rooting will not work on those devices!

Cite from the site root-apk.kingoapp.com

> It perfectly covers Android 1.5 to 5.0 mainstream models from different manufacturers including Samsung, Google, HTC, Sony and else.

Hence before installing any third party app you should read the documentation before installing and running it.

Comment: AFAIK Kingoroot and other similar rooting solutions rely on a range of exploits (which they don't expose unless reverse-engineered or leaked), not a single one. Though most of those (or possibly all) are fixed in Android 6+ releases. But still there is always a room for vendor-specific and model-specific exploits. However relying on exploits and using such solutions is obviously never recommended.