# Can't find stock rom for rooting

Tags: rooting, stock-rom

I want to root this phone ([HTC U12 life](https://forum.xda-developers.com/u12-life)) but cannot find source rom for it. I've checked a ton of websites (including [htcdev](https://www.htcdev.com/)) but found nothing. It looks like, this phone has been forsaken for a while now, so I am getting kinda desperate. However, I managed to find a [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/u12-life/how-to/discuss-htc-u12-life-root-achieved-t3923639) on XDA showing successful root of this phone, so there is still hope.The post is dead btw. Could you please give me a clue on where to get the rom? And if you can't, maybe there is a way to extract the rom from the phone itself or port a rom from another phone like [HTC U11 life](https://forum.xda-developers.com/u11-life)? I am not too advanced in android development but ready to learn if I have to. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: this dev successful built TWRP. unfortunately decided not to share. but have a look at his github there is HTC_OTA_Downloader which might help to get boot.img

Comment: To root your HTC U12 Life you can use one click root apps like Kingo Root.Can I post this as an answer?

Comment: @EliteX No, i would downvote https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706

Comment: Yes looks this seems no other way stocks roms not available I searched plenty.I admit I dont recommend most install malware but some good there and we should use when nothing solution left

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226198

Comment: android.stackexchange.com/q/226198 - is my post too. I had lost my password for this account back then but got it back already. And I have already tried one click rooting apps but none of them worked for me. And yes my bootloader is unlocked.