# How to root a HTC U12 Life without source code?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, htc, stock-rom

I have HTC U12 life. The problem is that, I want to root it, but I just cannot find its source code anywhere: no stock rom and no source kernel. Nothing. Neither on official resources nor on regular websites and forums. And the phone was released two years ago. Is there any way to root my phone without source code or to get the source code somehow? And by the way the phone is 100% rootable because I've seen a [post](https://forum.xda-developers.com/u12-life/how-to/discuss-htc-u12-life-root-achieved-t3923639) on XDA showing a successful root.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226146

Comment: the better question is how to dump firmware off the device. you need [boot.img](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#boot-image-patching) for rooting, unlocked bootloader or HTC specific [Qualcomm Firehose Loader](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=11410963190603890364) for flashing/dumping in [EDL mode](https://github.com/bkerler/edl)

Comment: akecxs, thanks for giving a clue. Could you please post a guide or some kind of manual on how to pull off the dumping? It's not like I am lazy, just want to follow up a reliable information you reccomend if, for sure, you know the subject.

Comment: have you unlocked bootloader? https://www.htcdev.com/bootloader