# Whatsapp backup for new and old chats

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, data-recovery, 7.0-nougat

I recently accidentally deleted a chat in Whatsapp for Android 7.0 "Nougat". I know if you uninstall and reinstall the app, you can download the backup containing these old messages. Now my problem is, this certain contact messaged me again after deleting the chat, so if I use the uninstall method, I lose all the chats from after the deleted ones. If I say "backup now" as to keep the new messages, it will delete the old backed up messages and only keep the new ones. Is there any way I can have my bread buttered on both sides and get my old messages back while still keeping the new ones?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Unless your device is rooted and you merge both databases, which is complicated and results in varying success!//mail yourself those chats from the contact and keep it safe. You have a record that can be used though not in chat format. //Delete and restore account  with old backup as usual

Answer (score 1):

If these messages are important, you can root your phone in order to restore them.

There are many [methods](https://www.xda-developers.com/best-one-click-root-2018/) to root Android 7 to use at your own risk.

WhatsApp make a backup of the messages database each day at 2:00 AM, these databases are stored encrypted in `/sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/`. The key used to encrypt the backup is stored in `/data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key` which can be accessed only if you have root privileges.

To restore your previous messages:

- root your phone
- enable USB debugging
- dump the encrypted databases

```
adb shell pull /sdcard/WhatsApp/Databases/
```

- dump the key

```
adb shell pull /data/data/com.whatsapp/files/key
```

- use this [python script](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/decrypting-whatsapp-crypt12-files-t3484491) to decrypt the encrypted databases:

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2896496

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706