# How to root access a motorola one fusion plus

Tags: rooting, root-access, android-10, systemless-root

I don't have a pc and I want to root my motorola one fusion+ I've tried kingroot farmaroot

Comment: Your device is from 2020, those old rooting tools only work with ancient Android versions. May be you should just stick to the official way: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/standalone/bootloader/unlock-your-device-a Note that doing so usually will void warranty. But a PC is needed, without you won't succeed.

Comment: Relevant: [Why are the rooting apps not working anymore?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/96277)