# how to root Samsung tab SM-T150

Tags: root-access

Hi i wanted to root my Samsung tablet model Galaxy Tab SM-T150 which turned out harder than i expected.

I am a android 11 user btw if it helps

I tried the one click root apps like Kingo root, king root, frama root etc but in both kingo root and king root it does not work and frama root says that my device is not  vulnerable to the exploit. Also i have tried all the other apps like towel root etc and nothing seems to work. (I do not have a pc so do not suggest abd)

Then i saw magisk and super su and i installed there zip files and tried moving them to my sd card but for some reason it is set to read only so i cant move anything to the sd card.

I removed it but it did not have any on off button and when i put it back in i cant remove it out again.

I tried to install TWRP custom recovery but that itself needs root and did not work out.

Please any suggestions will work and pls help me any thing that works  will be appreciated:)

Comment: "*TWRP custom recovery but that itself needs root*" what's needed is an unlocked bootloader, not a rooted device. The general process is: unlock bootloader -> flash custom recovery -> flash Magisk (modified boot image). Also, [most rooting apps won't work anymore since Android 6.0](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/44325).

Comment: Also, just to clarify, is it T**15**0 or T**51**0? Related on XDA Forums for the latter: [Bootloader unlock for 2019 Galaxy Tab A 10.1 \[SM-T510/T515\]](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bootloader-unlock-for-2019-galaxy-tab-a-10-1-sm-t510-t515.3926617/)