# Can Samsung be rooted without computer?

Tags: samsung, rooting

I have Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra. I'm thinking of rooting it. Is rooting possible without a computer? In some places, they say you can do it, in other places, they say you can't. If you google how to root S20 Ultra without a computer, a lot of results and guides show up.

So what is the truth, is rooting without a computer possible?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/4215101

Comment: Some "guides" are auto-generated using the same template for other devices, and thus some are unreliable. Based on my very limited experience, rooting without a computer was possible for older Android versions using exploits, but [not so much for newer Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/44325) such as Galaxy S20.