# Is it possible to backup absolutely everything?

Tags: backup, samsung-galaxy-j7

My phone is having issues, so I'd like to know if it's possible to backup **everything**, so apps, app data, files, pretty much every little thing.

(My phone is a Samsung J7 Star that's unrooted)

Comment: Without root, it's practically impossible since each app can decide whether it is allowed to be backed up or not, and its data cannot be accessed without root access.

Comment: Would I be able to root my phone and keep everything, because I'd do it if it means I can fix the issue or backup everything

Comment: The common way to root is by unlocking the bootloader and flashing a custom recovery first, but unlocking the bootloader will factory reset the device. On the other hand, rooting apps may be able to bypass the requirements, but [they may not work anymore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/44325).

Comment: Alright, thank you